# A play in which the characters murder the author

Tags: identification-request, german-language, ludwig-tieck

The following sentence appears on p.26, Chapter 2 of Walter Frisch's *Music in the Nineteenth Century*:

> In one play by Ludwig Tieck, the characters gang up at the end and
> murder the author.

However, no further reference is given as to which play it is. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps there is another play of Tieck's with which I'm not familiar, but the epilogue to *Der gestiefelte Kater* sounds similar.

From Wikipedia:

> Im Widerspruch dazu, dass dem Publikum das Stück nicht gefällt, applaudieren die Zuschauer, da ihnen die Dekoration der letzten Szene sehr gut gefallen hat. Der Dichter erscheint und macht die Zuschauer für das Scheitern des Stückes verantwortlich. Er wirft ihnen vor, das Stück für etwas Wichtigeres zu halten, als es sein sollte. Daraufhin jagen die Zuschauer den Dichter von der Bühne.

And in English (via Google Translate):

> Contrary to the fact that the audience does not like the play, the audience applauds because they liked the decoration of the last scene very much. The poet appears and blames the viewers for the failure of the play. He accuses them of considering the play to be something more important than it should be. The spectators then chase the poet off the stage.

So, the characters in the main story don't kill him, but the audience, characters in the play regardless, do chase him away. The verb *jagen* can mean "to hunt," and is a word used with hunting animals, so perhaps that's where Frisch got the idea from, if this is the play he has in mind.